# Postgres: order data by part of string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column name that represents a person's name in the following format:

```
firstname [middlename] lastname [, Sr.|Jr.]
```

For, example:

```
John Smith
John J. Smith
John J. Smith, Sr.
```

How can I order items by lastname?

Comment: In an ideal world, you would choose to store the name parts in seperate fields

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A *correct* and faster version could look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY substring(name, '([^[:space:]]+)(?:,|$)')
```

Or:

```
ORDER  BY substring(name, E'([^\\s]+)(?:,|$)')
```

Or even:

```
ORDER  BY substring(name, E'([^\\s]+)(,|$)')
```

#### Explain

`[^[:space:]]+` .. first (and longest) string consisting of one or more non-whitespace characters.
`(,|$)` .. terminated by a comma or the end of the string.

The last two examples use escape-string syntax and the [class-shorthand `\s`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE) instead of the long form `[[:space:]]` (which loses the outer level of brackets when inside a character class).

We don't actually have to use non-capturing parenthesis `(?:)` *after* the part we want to extract, because ([quoting the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)):

> .. if the pattern contains any parentheses, the portion of the text that
>   matched the first parenthesized subexpression (the one whose left
>   parenthesis comes first) is returned.

#### Test

```
SELECT substring(name, '([^[:space:]]+)(?:,|$)')
FROM  (VALUES 
  ('John Smith')
 ,('John J. Smith')
 ,('John J. Smith, Sr.')
 ,('foo bar Smith, Jr.')
) x(name)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use functional index for this purpose
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/indexes-functional.html

In your case somehow....

```
CREATE INDEX test1_lastname_col1_idx ON test1 (split_part(col1, ' ', 3));
SELECT * FROM test1 ORDER BY split_part(col1, ' ', 3);
```

Comment: This does not work, because `lastname` isn't always the third element.

Comment: You can change the string expression in order to your needs, its not so hard to do using regexps or this manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html
, but the main idea of my post was to attract attention to CREATE INDEX statement, because select will take extremely long time without index.

Comment: Oh, I've mistaken this url leads to MySQL manual))) Here is the right one http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM t
ORDER BY substring(name, E'^.*\\s([^\\s]+)(?=,|$)') ASC
```

While this should provide the sorting you are looking for, it would be a lot cheaper to store the name in multiple columns and index them based on which parts of the name you need to sort by.

Comment: Thank you, this will probably solve the problem as long as raw sql is concerned.

Comment: The regular expression is actually *incorrect*. Try: `SELECT substring('John J. Smith, Sr.', E'^.*\\s([^\\s]+)(?=,|$)')`. I posted a version that works.